# Microservices Java Web Application RunTime Issue after upgrading to Java17

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jaxb, cxf

These are my Error Tomcat Logs for my Java Spring Framework Application .

```
31-Jan-2024 23:11:52.339 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
31-Jan-2024 23:11:54.619 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
31-Jan-2024 23:11:57.630 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restEndpointsServer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1589)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:554)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4494)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4946)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:662)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:689)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1888)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:582)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1617)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:318)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:893)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:795)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1328)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1318)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:249)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:922)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
    Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:220)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1719)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1656)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1585)
        ... 53 more
    Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: No resource classes found
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.checkResources(AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.java:318)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:156)
        ... 60 more
31-Jan-2024 23:11:57.760 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
31-Jan-2024 23:11:58.397 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
31-Jan-2024 23:11:58.397 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
31-Jan-2024 23:11:58.399 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@7d957c96')
31-Jan-2024 23:11:58.644 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
31-Jan-2024 23:11:58.644 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
```

1. Java- 17 eclipse adoptium open jdk
2. Tomcat version- 9.0.78
3. Spring Version - 5.3.13
4. Spring Security Version- 5.3.13.RELEASE
5. cxf.version-3.5.0

   I have excluded al the duplicate dependencies those come with Jakarta changes in CXF. I have tried changing dependency versions and spring versions , I'm able to build with Maven, But When I deploy the generated war file with Tomcat Application doesn't start .
   Below is my POM

   ````
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>xxxxxxxxx</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>xxxxx</name>
        <packaging>pom</packaging>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
                <artifactId>unitils-core</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
                <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <nexus.url>https://xxx.xxx.ca/nexus/repository/maven-public</nexus.url>
            <spring.version>5.3.13</spring.version>
            <spring-security.version>5.3.13.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
            <cxf.version>3.5.0</cxf.version>
            <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
            <test.type>integration</test.type>
            <thymeleaf.version>3.0.0.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
            <sso.shared>1910.0.8</sso.shared>
        </properties>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>nexus</id>
                <url>${nexus.url}</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>nexus</id>
                <url>${nexus.url}</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
        <build>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.8.1</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.2</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.10.4</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.19.1</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.3.2</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.2</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.7.9</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <release>17</release>
                        <!--<compilerArgument>-Xlint:deprecation</compilerArgument>-->
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>../testng-${test.type}.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                        <argLine>
                                -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                        </argLine>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <reporting>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </reporting>
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- Internal dependencies -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        Internal Dependencies
                    <!-- External dependencies -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                        <version>6.10</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.8</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
                        <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.6</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7.22</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7.22</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7.22</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7.22</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.0</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                        <version>20.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
                        <version>1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                        <version>2.8.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4.0</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.networknt</groupId>
                        <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
                        <version>0.1.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- remove the following dependencies if you don't support XML in the REST calls -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
                        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4.9</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.1</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- end of block to be removed if you don't support XML in the REST calls -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
                        <artifactId>unitils-core</artifactId>
                        <version>3.4.3</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.xxx.innocache</groupId>
                        <artifactId>innocache</artifactId>
                        <version>1404.0.5</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- remove cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws if you don't make SOAP calls to other services -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
                        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
                        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
                        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
                        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
                        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5.5</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
                        <version>12.1.0.2</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
                        <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
                        <version>4.8</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                        <version>4.5.5</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- Thymeleaf library -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
                        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
                        <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
                        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
                        <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- SSO for My CreditCards app -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.xxx.security.common</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-security-asserter</artifactId>
                        <version>${sso.shared}</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                    <!--
                    kass - remove this eventually
                    -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.xxx.security.common</groupId>
                        <artifactId>xxx-common-security-env</artifactId>
                        <version>${sso.shared}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </dependencyManagement>
            <profiles>
                <profile>
                    <!-- calculate coverage metrics per test with SonarQube and JaCoCo -->
                    <id>coverage-per-test</id>
                    <properties>
                    </properties>
                    <build>
                        <plugins>
                            <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                <executions>
                                    <execution>
                                        <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </execution>
                                    <execution>
                                        <id>post-unit-test</id>
                                        <phase>test</phase>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>report</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </execution>
                                    <execution>
                                        <id>report-aggregate</id>
                                        <phase>verify</phase>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </execution>
                                </executions>
                            </plugin>
                            <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                                <configuration>
                                    <!-- same configuration as in the regular test execution goal -->
                                    <!-- plus argLine parameter configured by JaCoCo prepare-agent -->
                                    <argLine>${argLine}                         -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                                    </argLine>
                                    <properties>
                                        <property>
                                            <name>listener</name>
                                            <value>org.sonar.java.jacoco.TestNGListener</value>
                                        </property>
                                    </properties>
                                </configuration>
                            </plugin>
                        </plugins>
                    </build>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java</groupId>
                            <artifactId>sonar-jacoco-listeners</artifactId>
                            <version>2.3</version>
                            <scope>test</scope> ```
   ````

Comment: Your problem seems to be due to a `org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException `. According to the [documentation](https://cxf.apache.org/download.html), [Apache CFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_CXF) version 3.6.2 supports a "move to a fully JDK-11 baseline" … "yet remains JEE 8.x compatible(javax.* namespace)". Perhaps your 3.5.x version should be updated.

Comment: Could you share the pom dependencies related section please ?

Comment: Yes @LaurentSchoelens .Shared my POM above. Please check

Comment: @LaurentSchoelens This is the same POM file you have seen previously on my other post for HTTP Blocker Issue, For that there were duplicate dependencies I had excluded them then Was able to compile the code. Duplicates came from CXF Update.

Comment: The error seems present because the application doesn't find any class annotated with `@javax.ws.rs.Path` : could you please check your application code and share how you create your `JAXRSServerFactoryBean` ?

Comment: @LaurentSchoelens Actually I didn't change any application code at all, Just added annotation-api dependency and excluded all the jakarta dependencies. Updated Spring,cxf versions

Comment: Are you sure that some "jakarta" dependencies you excluded are jakarta-based package ?

Comment: @LaurentSchoelens IN my whole project I don't find Jakarta mentioned anywhere actually, and this is a really old project which was running on Java 8 and Spring 4 version. My task is to upgrade it and make it run on Java17. So I just excluded Jakarta dependencies which caused so many conflicts and troubles.

Comment: I also tried to move to jakarta but facing some issue like one is this "at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.ForkOnceWSDL2Java.main(ForkOnceWSDL2Java.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException"
So decided to stick with Javax.

Comment: Moving to jakarta error : I guess you've missed CXF plugin upgrade (to v4). For the jakarta dependencies in javax context like `javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1` and `jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api2.3.3` which are both javax-based jaxb-api EE8.

Comment: @LaurentSchoelens Tried that as well , Same exact error.